# Android ASOP build error while adding third party plugin of Firebase in Android.bp

Tags: android, firebase, build-system, android-soong

I'm trying to build an ASOP build which uses some external libs like Firebase. (In ASOP source code)

While adding Firebase plugin in Android.bp getting error like "**depends on undefined module "com.google.gms.google-services**"

Is there any alternative to use "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" in Andorid.mk or Android.bp other build system?

```
android_app {
name: "FirebaseService",
vendor: true,
certificate: "platform",
privileged: true,
srcs: ["java/**/*.java",],
resource_dirs: ["res"],
manifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",

static_libs: [
    "firebase-analytics",
    "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",

],
plugins: ["com.google.gms.google-services"],

optimize: {
    enabled: false,
},
sdk_version: "system_current",
dex_preopt: {
    enabled: false,
}, }
```

This plugin is to use refer google-sevices.json file  which we get while integrate application with Firebase.

```
error: vendor/frameworks/FirebaseService/Android.bp:20:1:"FirebaseService" depends on undefined module "com.google.gms.google-services"
```